# How to read the user input on the client-side, modify it with JS on the client-side, and then POST it to the sever-side (Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, client, ejs

**Problem**: I want to read a user input on the client-side, do some processing on the variable using JavaScript, still on the client-side, then POST the modified variable to the server-side (Node.js).
**Research**: There are a few similar questions on Stackoverflow, but the answers are not the questions to my requirement. I read about Ajax and Fetch, but they focused on collecting info from the server rather than sending a JS variable from the client-side to the server. I am not sure about using WebSockets for such a simple task.

**Code:**
The following code is in an EJS template.
I want to POST variable name to Node.js in the following code:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input id = "name" type="text"> <br><br>
        <label for="name">City: </label>
        <input id = "city" type="text"> <br><br>
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        <button id="capitalize">Capitalize Everything</button>
        <button id="clear">Clear</button>
    </div>

    <p>
        Your name is <span id="outputName">____</span>. The city in which you live is <span id = "outputCity">____.</span>
    </p>


    <script>
        var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
        submit.onclick = () => {
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
            name = "+" + name //some processing on varibale name, can be anything else
            document.getElementById("outputName").innerText = name;
            document.getElementById("outputCity").innerText = city;
        }   
    </script>

    <form action="/posty" method="post">
        <label for="verse"></label>Search The Bible <br></label>
        <input type="hidden" id ="id" name = "name" value = "name">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    
</body>
```

The related serverside code:

```
app.post('/posty', (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body.name)
})
```

In the following:

```
<input type="hidden" id ="id" name = "name" value = "name">
```

what is transferred to the server is the string "name" , not the content of the JS variable name. I tried to put the name between <%= %> as it was an ejs template, but it didn't work.

**Problem Summary**: How to read the user input on the client-side, modify it with JS on the client-side, and then POST it to the sever-side (Node.js)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use Ajax to Post data to your route (/posty).

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit", function () {
  
          var name=$('#name').val()
          var city =$('#city').val()
          var outputName=$('#outputName').text('name')
          var outputCity=$('#outputCity').text('city')
          var id= $('#id').attr('id')
          
          var obj=JSON.stringify({
            name:name,
            city:city,
            id:id,
            outputName:outputName,
            outputCity:outputCity
       })

 
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/posty",
          data:obj,
          contentType: "application/json",
          beforeSend:function(){
         //can put some spinner,before request
          },
          success: function (res) {
            //respond from Backend
            
            if(res){
          ...
            }
          },
        });
      });



//On server side

  app.post("/posty", urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await db.query(...);
          res.send(true);
    }
      } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    })
```

Sorry for Jquery,its easier to write..

Comment: Thank you. I have to research how can I rewrite this in Vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the name attribute correctly of each input, so that you can send a HTTP POST request with the payload you want.

```html
<body>
  <form action="/posty" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text">

    <label for="city">City: </label>
    <input id="city" name="city" type="text">
  
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

If you want to modify the input value before sending the request, you can define a custom function, modify input value in it, and use the [native fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to send it.

```html
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function customSubmit() {
      const name = document.getElementById('name').value + ' mock';
      const city = document.getElementById('city').value + ' mock';
      fetch('/posty', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, city })
      })
    }
  </script>
  <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); customSubmit()">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text">

    <label for="city">City: </label>
    <input id="city" name="city" type="text">

    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>  
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clean and complete code. I tried your code, and I got the following message: "undefined". I tried console.log(req.body) and I get an empty object { } . Also, I tried req.body.id, req.body.city, none of them works. Should l I install node-fetch for node.js before running your code? Best regards

Comment: When I replace <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); customSubmit()"> with <form action="/posty" method ="POST"> then in the server-side I can get the object including name and the city. There is something with either <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); customSubmit()"> or the JS code , or fetch. If I install node-fetch then I am not sure how to use it in JS in the html page (I am using an EJS template instead of html with node.js/express). Thank you

Comment: I think it's not a dependencies problem, fetch API is very common in browser environments right now (you can check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=fetch), it shows fetch API has 93.65% global usage of all users), perhaps you are using IE as your browser environment I guess, which is the only browser not implement fetch API, otherwise you can use fetch API without install any dependencies.

Comment: Before submitting your form, open browser devtools first and go to the Network tab, then submit your form, and check whether your request is sent with the correct payload or not.

[https://i.imgur.com/iTPDTBo.png](https://i.imgur.com/iTPDTBo.png)

Comment: Thank you.  I had to add headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }) to the fetch block to get it working also, I had to add app.use(express.json()) to the server-side code. Then it works. However, I was watching a YouTube video about Fetch, and the instruction didn't use headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }) in the fetch block, and he could post at least within the browser, but it doesn't work for me using Chrome.